# Execution order of list comprehension filtering

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Just started learning Haskell and came across this issue. 
If I have a list comprehension with a condition such as

```
[x*2 | x<- [1..10], x `mod` 3 ==2]
```

I get

```
[4,10,16]
```

as expected. However, if I have instead

```
[x**2 | x<- [1..10], x `mod` 3 ==2]
```

It is has the type variable as ambiguous for the mod function. I presume this is because x<sup>2</sup> promotes an integer to a float, but why does this affect the conditional? Why is the type ambiguous in this case? Does it calculate x<sup>2</sup>, and then square root it? (This seems highly improbable) Does it somehow keep track of the x that generated each x<sup>2</sup> term?

Perhaps it's the imperative mindset, but internally, I thought the execution would be along the lines of [in python]

```
lst=[]
for x in range(10):
 if x%3==2:
  lst.append(x**2)
```

Could someone clarify/correct my understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have a look at the types of `mod` and `(**)`:

```
mod  :: Integral n => n -> n -> n
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
     -- hm......
```

`mod` and `(**)` put other constraints on the used type. `mod` expects an integral type (`Int`, `Integer`), whereas `(**)` expects a floating type (`Float`, `Double`). Since there's no type that's both integral *and* a floating point number, GHC gives up.

Instead, use `(^)`:

```
(^) :: (Integral n, Num a) => a -> n -> a
```

E.g.

```
[x ^ 2 | x <- [1..10], x `mod` 3 == 2]
```

By the way, you can find errors like this easier if you try to give a type to the result:

```
ghci> [x ** 2 | x <- [1..10], x `mod` 3 == 2] :: [Int]
<interactive>:1:4:
    No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `**'
    In the expression: x ** 2
    ...
```

Comment: I guess my question is that why is the promotion of ** executed prior to mod? Or does it try to reconcile all things first?

Comment: @Untitled123: yes, it always tries to reconcile all things first. There is _no such thing_ as type promotion in Haskell!

Answer (score 2):

The first example works because of defaulting. The expression is inferred as having type

```
Integral a => [a]
```

and then the `a` type variable is defaulted to `Integer` for convenience.

In the second expression, the use of `**` forces `x` to be `Floating` and the `mod` forces it to be `Integral`. So GHC infers that the expression has type

```
(Integral a, Floating a) => [a]
```

There is no standard numeric type that is both `Integral` and `Floating`, let alone one that participates in defaulting.

You mentioned the notion of numeric promotion in your question. C, C++, Java, and maybe some other languages have such a thing. Haskell does not, and those of us who use it tend to be grateful for that. All conversions from one numeric type to another have to be done using explicit conversion functions like `fromIntegral`, `fromRational`, `round`, `floor`, `%`, etc.

You probably meant to use `^` instead of `**`, which would leave just the `Integral a` constraint. In a real program, you should generally *avoid* the defaulting mechanism by including a type signature. You can turn it off altogether using

```
default ()
```

somewhere in your module.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension in haskell desugars to a do-block using the list monad. In your example,  it would be something like:

```
x <- [1..10]
guard $ (x `mod` 3) == 2
return $ x**2
```

In this case it attempts to unify the types of `(**) x 2` and `mod x 3` which fails because you [can't](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers#Converting_between_different_floating-point_precisions) unify a Floating type with an Integral type without explicitly converting between the two.

You've got a few options: use  `(^^)` instead of `(**)` or do `((fromIntegral x) ** 2)` if you want `x` to be an integral type, or somehow round `x` to an integral type if you want it to be a floating type.

Comment: Do you mean `(^)` rather than `(^^)`?

Comment: `(^)` returns an integral type, so it really depends on what you want.

Comment: I see. It's just I get an error when trying the original code using `(^^)`—because it's not a ratio, of course. But yes, `(^)` works fine.